# Possible syntax error in batch-file calling the FOR /F function

Tags: batch-file, ssl-certificate

I'm running into what I believe is a syntax issue with my batch script. I am trying to pass a command to FOR /F to read, but I think the format of the command is not correct. Here is the command I am trying to pass to FOR /F:

```
"C:\Program Files\Tomcat\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -destkeystore "C:\Certificate\certificate.pfx" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass password123
```

This command itself seems formatted fine, as it runs and gives me the proper output.

But when I try to pass the command to FOR /F like so:

```
SET ParentDirectory=C:\Program Files\Tomcat\
SET CertPath=C:\Certficate\certificate.pfx
SET CertPassword=password123

FOR /f "skip=5 tokens=1 delims=," %%G in ('"%ParentDirectory%jre^\bin^\keytool.exe" -list -destkeystore "%CertPath%" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass %CertPassword%') do (
    ECHO.
    ECHO %%G
)
PAUSE
```

I get error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So I feel like the syntax for the command within the FOR /F loop is wrong, maybe some different combination of quotes and backslashes...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting gets a little tricky inside the IN clause of a `FOR` command.  You essentially need to quote the entire line of code you are executing plus escape those extra quotes as well.  There was no need to escape the back slashes like you were doing.

```
FOR /f "skip=5 tokens=1 delims=," %%G in ('^""%ParentDirectory%jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -destkeystore "%CertPath%" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass %CertPassword%^"') do (
```

Answer (score 0):

The command after `in` within parentheses actually becomes executed by [`cmd /C`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), which has got some particular treatment of quotation. So the following is going to be executed:

```cmd
cmd /C "%ParentDirectory%\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -destkeystore "%CertPath%" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass %CertPassword%
```

Now from the usage information of `cmd /?`:

> ```cmd
> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
> the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
> used to process quote (") characters:
>
>     1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>         on the command line are preserved:
>
>         - no /S switch
>         - exactly two quote characters
>         - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>           where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>         - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>           two quote characters
>         - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>           of an executable file.
>
>     2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>         a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>         remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>         any text after the last quote character.
> ```

We fall into category `2.` because there are more than two `"`-characters, resulting in the command line to be executed:

```cmd
%ParentDirectory%\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -destkeystore "%CertPath% -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass %CertPassword%
```

Which is definitely wrong syntax.

The optimal solution has already been provided by [Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381554). The additional pair of surrounding quotation marks is removed by `cmd /C`, leaving behind a syntactically correct command line to be executed:

```cmd
"%ParentDirectory%\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -destkeystore "%CertPath%" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass %CertPassword%
```

---

Here is the complete corrected script, with some further minor corrections and improvements:

```cmd
rem /* Use quoted `set` syntax to protect special characters and avoid unintended trailing white-spaces;
rem    note, that this requires Command Extensions to be enabled, but which is the default anyway: */
set "ParentDirectory=%ProgramFiles%\Tomcat" & rem // (avoid trailing `\` and put hem in later)
set "CertPath=C:\Certficate\certificate.pfx"
set "CertPassword=password123"

rem /* Add a pair of surrounding escaped quotation marks to protect the command line;
rem    escaping of them is needed for the command line to appear unquoted to the parser;
rem    that way, any potential escaping does not have to be altered: */
for /F "skip=5 tokens=1 delims=," %%G in ('^""%ParentDirectory%\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -list -destkeystore "%CertPath%" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass %CertPassword%^"') do (
    rem // Better use `echo/` instead of `echo.` to output a blank line:
    echo/
    rem // Better use `echo(` to safely output an arbitrary (potentially empty) line:
    echo(%%G
)
pause
```